# How to create column-wise array from a set of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to combine a set of array by column?

```
# input
arr = [[100, 99, 98], [100, 97, 92], [63, 89, 63], [99, 99, 99], [89, 97, 98]]

# output
result = [[100, 100, 63, 99, 89], [99, 97, 89, 99, 97], [98, 92, 63, 99, 98]]
```

Or in other words:

```
# input
arr = [
  [100, 99, 98],
  [100, 97, 92],
  [63, 89, 63],
  [99, 99, 99],
  [89, 97, 98]
]

# output
result = [
  [100, 100, 63, 99, 89],
  [99, 97, 89, 99, 97],
  [98, 92, 63, 99, 98]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) does that:

```
result = arr.transpose
p result #=> [[100, 100, 63, 99, 89], [99, 97, 89, 99, 97], [98, 92, 63, 99, 98]]
```